# HTTP Requests for Git Server

Tags: git, http

If a remote git server uses HTTP, I figure it must be possible to interact with it using only HTTP requests without using the git programme.

How can this be done?

The reason I am asking is to try and create a git client with the iPadOS Shortcuts app (a GUI-based scripting programme). I’d use git and shell script if I could, but here I am trying to make my iPad compatible with my Linux laptop. Not sure what I was hoping for really.

Anyway, this obviously this has certain issues like not tracking changes. I just wanted to know if this was, by any hack method, possible.

Comment: "*How can this be done?*" By implementing Git Protocol yourself. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68062812/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+implement+protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP to interact with git. The protocol documentation for that is available here: https://git-scm.com/docs/http-protocol